# Websocket connection closing immediately on connect with no apparent reason

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, multiprocessing

I am writing a multiplayer package for games using websockets. I have a server file and a client file in the package and two separate test files set up for testing the package, one a server, one a client.

My problem is that when run the server and connect to it via the client, it will connect and then immediately disconnect. When looking at the traceback, there is no apparent reason for why it disconnected.

Traceback:

```
Connected
connection handler failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\websockets\legacy\server.py", line 240, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self)
  File "C:\Users\diarm\Documents\GitHub\pymultiplayer\pymultiplayer\server.py", line 16, in connection_handler
    helper_process.start()
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 94, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 111, in spawn_main
    new_handle = reduction.duplicate(pipe_handle,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 79, in duplicate
    return _winapi.DuplicateHandle(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

All files:
https://github.com/iamdeedz/pymultiplayer/blob/backbone

I have looked up `OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid` and `TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object` with no result. I have asked this question elsewhere and haven't gotten an answer. I was trying to connect to the server, and send some test data.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is namely these two lines:

```py
 File "C:\Users\diarm\Documents\GitHub\pymultiplayer\pymultiplayer\server.py", line 16, in connection_handler
    helper_process.start()
  File "C:\Users\diarm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
```

As you've correctly identified, the error is `TypeError: cannot pickle '_asyncio.Future' object`. This is because the `Future` belongs to a thread on the main process you're running in, which is the event loop for the main process. When you send it to a new process with `POpen`, then it's link to this thread becomes destroyed and it will never be updated.

Without knowing the rest of your code, it's hard to really say how to fix this but in general, you should `await` the result/exception of this `asyncio.Future` and send that through to the subprocess. If you need constant communication between the two, i.e. the main process and the `POpen` process you make, you could take a look at [`Queue`s or `Pipe`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) with `Queue` being some extra functionality built on top of `Pipe`.

Comment: My code is there. At the github page I linked. I am awaiting the only `asyncio.Future` I have in my code. What do you mean by sending it through itthe subprocess?